# How to use URL class in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have been doing a live streaming app for Blackberry.I have the android code for the application.I need to implement in blackberry now.So in the android code they are importing the packages namely

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

which are not supported in blackberry.For the `HttpURLConnection`,i have found a corresponding class in blackberry api,its called `HttpsConnection`.But for the URL class i am not being able to find any corresponding class in blackberry api.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Use these packages:

```
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
```

and open the connection like that:

```
String urlString = "http://www.myserver.com/myresource/somethinghere";
HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(urlString);
java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.openInputStream();
```